# Crow probability question

Tags: probability, expectation

Twenty crows land randomly on a wire. Each crow is crowing at the nearest crow.
What is the expected number of crows that are not crowed at?

I truly have no idea how to approach this problem.

I was thinking along the lines that the end crows each have probability $\frac12$ of not being crowed at. The penultimate crows on each end have $0$ probability of not being crowed at. For each "interior" crow, the probability of not being crowed at is $\frac14$. So the expected number of crows that are not crowed at is $2\cdot\frac12+16\cdot\frac14=5$.

Comment: Could you at least show an attempt?

Comment: I was thinking along the lines that the end crows each have probability 1/2 of not being crowed at. The penultimate crows on each end have 0 probability of not being crowed at. For each "interior" crow, the probability of not being crowed at is 1/4. So the expected number of crows that are not crowed at is 2⋅12+16⋅14=5.

Comment: The phrase "land randomly" is ambiguous, as there are many distributions that could be used. Are you assuming that the "nearest crow" is the left one with probability $1/2$ and the right one with the same probability (excepting the ones at the ends)?

Comment: @user185704: That sounds right. You should probably mention the magic word "linearity of expectation" somewhere, and add some explanations of how you find the numbers 1/2 and 1/4.

Comment: @Rory: It seems reasonable to interpret it such that each crow independently selects a position uniformly over the length of the wire.

Comment: What if, for example, three crows are evenly spaced out? Would the middle crow crow at both its neighbors?

Comment: I answered it, though I guess I will never get as the accepted answer... The user never came back.

Answer (score 1):

Put the first crow in the wire. Now the second, at distance $\delta_1$, taken from the random variable $\Delta$ (*never found myself using $\Delta$ for a random variable before*). As stated, this will be crowed at with probability $1$, so if $C_n$ is the event of the $n^{th}$ crow being crowed at, $$P(C_2)=1$$

Now take a $\delta_2$ for determining the distance between the second and the third crow. $P(C_1)=P(\Delta>\delta_1)$. Since $\delta1$ comes from $\Delta$, $$P(C_1)=P(\Delta>\Delta')=\frac{1}{2}$$

Now take a $\delta_3$ for determining the distance between the third and the fourth crow, and so on. For any interior crow, then, $$P(C_n)=P(\delta_n<\delta_{n-1}\cup\delta_n<\delta_{n+1})=\\
P(\delta_n<\delta_{n-1})+P(\delta_n<\delta_{n+1})-P(\delta_n<\delta_{n-1}\cap\delta_n<\delta_{n+1})=\\
\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}-P(\Delta<\Delta'\cap\Delta<\Delta'')=1-\frac{2}{6}=\frac{2}{3}
$$

For the last part of the calculus, you basicaly have three random variables following the same distribution, so you have six equiprobable ways to order $\Delta, \Delta', \Delta''$, and only in two of them $\Delta$ is the smallest.

And finally,
 $$P(C_{19})=P(C_2)=1\\
P(C_{20})=P(C_1)=\frac{1}{2}
$$

For the expected number, let's sum all this.
$$E[C]=2\frac{1}{2}+2+16\frac{2}{3}=\frac{41}{3}\\
E[C^C]=20-E[C]=\frac{19}{3}\approx 6.3
$$

And this is it, the expected number of uncrowed crows is $6.3$